# Mint login screen different keyboard layout per user

Tags: linux-mint, login, keyboard-layout

Is there a possibility to have a different keyboard layout per user login in Mint 17.1?  If so, how?

I am using a US keyboard layout; my girlfriend uses a German (DE) keyboard layout (on the same computer). 
Changing it for the user in the `.dmrc` file is already done and working after I successfully login. 
However, the layout on the login page is either DE or US. I didn't find a solution to have it change automatically when I focus on the respective user login.

I found [this "Mint login screen: wrong keyboard layout" question](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136382/mint-login-screen-wrong-keyboard-layout), but it doesn't solve my problem since the accepted answer changes the layout permanently for all users.